# No user account being generated. only guest log in

Tags: login

I bought a Dell Vostro 3558 laptop with preinstalled ubuntu 14.04 
It is only showing guest account log in. Not able to generate my personal account.it is not even taking password  to unlock account.
Please guide.
Mahen